# Trouble accessing ntfs drives in mac os x

Tags: macos, ntfs

I installed tuxera-ntfs in mac os x and am able to mount my external disks and use them without any issues.

I can delete files, copy files to my external disk and from my disk

But I am not able to cut the files(use the cmd+X) . Any files that I copied from my external disk to my mac, I face the same issue.

Also I am not able to change user permission by using `chmod` for any of the files.

I have two disks and the behaviour is the same in both of them

I want to know if this is a default behavior of using ntfs drives in mac or I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please do not cross-post to multiple SE sites.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not know there was a `stack exchange` for apple. Did not know how to move the questions from superuser to here.
Any knowledge of this weird thing that i am encountering.

Comment: I answered the first part over in SU. idk on the 2nd part, sorry. Not even sure how NTFS & what is essentially a nix command are going to get along. Did you try Get Info & see what is available there for perms?

Comment: maybe - http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/

Answer (score -1):

i use this i have not problems http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26288/ntfs you can try !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: nothing to comment i just said that this app would help him better. at least it have done with me. works very naturally and read ntfs file and write to because mac read but for some reason that i think is related with the license of use for mac. osx do not write in ntfs hard-disk or format partition with this format. but this plug in help make your operative system able to do it. i do understand that he alreay is using one that is not do it right.
i have use this and works fine: 
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26288/ntfs

So probably he want to test that instead.